# Use EF 6.0 SaveChanges() function causes error "Could not load file or assembly " oracle. manageddataaccessdtc, version=4.122.19.1"

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, oracle.manageddataaccess

I use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` nuget packet, I publish the project to IIS, everything it ok, but if I call the EF function `SaveChanges()`, I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342 Or one of its dependencies,Find the assembly manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. ( exception from hresult:0x80131040 )

I put the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll` in the publish folder in the `bin` directory, but I still get the error.

Please give me some advice! Thanks!

Comment: can double check the version for your `Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll`, the particular error will be raised when 1) the assembly (`dll` file) is missing, 2) the version mismatched.

Comment: in my local iis it's ok,i think is environmental issues,but I don't know what environmental i can install

Comment: I install the microsoft visual c++ 2008-2015 in computer and republish the project,and restart, Problemo solved。